# jpa2 hibernate, a testcase to test lock over an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, locking, jpa-2.0

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.5.Final and JPA2

How can make a testcase to test if the hibernate lock is working?

I wrote this, but seems that the test not pass in the current hibernate version (works fine in the previous version)

```
@Test(expected=OptimisticLockException.class)
public void testLock() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Foo foo1 = fooDAO.findById(1);
    em.lock(foo1, LockModeType.WRITE);
    foo1.setCode("code3");
    em.flush();
}
```

EDIT:

@Pascal: that's what you mean in the second case?

```
@Test(expected=OptimisticLockException.class)
public void testLock() {
   EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   Foo foo1 = fooDAO.findById(1);
   em.lock(foo1, LockModeType.WRITE);
   fooDAO.createHibernateQuery("update Foo set version=version+1 where id = 1");
   foo1.setCode("code3");
   em.flush();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What is the error?  Fetching an object and validating it is a proper test.

Comment: I'm not getting the OptimisticLockException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any concurrent access in this test, there is no reason for it to fail IMO. 
If you want to test the behavior of *optimistic locking with version update*, you need to test something like this:

- Read Foo with Id = X in Persistence Context 1 (version is N)
- Read Foo with Id = X in Persistence Context 2 (version is N)
- Do some changes on the foo instance in PC 1
- Do some changes on the foo instance in PC 2
- Flush and commit the changes in PC 1 // should be ok (version becomes N + 1)
- Flush the changes in PC 2 // should throw exception

Using a single persistence context and a SQL query is another option:

- Read Foo with Id = X in Persistence Context 1 (version is N)
- Do some changes on the foo instance in PC 1
- Use SQL to UPDATE Foo set version = version + 1 WHERE id = X
- Flush the changes in PC 1 // should throw exception

#### See also

- [Locking and Concurrency in Java Persistence 2.0](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java)